# Why is my function not doing what its supposed to, changing the direction of the velocity of a ball in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, geometry

So I have made a little program, where i have a ball that is supposed to slowly accelerate when falling down and slowly decelerate when jumping up again. Meanwhile it is supposed to move to the left and to the right,  basically bouncing from side to side.

The problem I have now, is that the method that is supposed to make the ball change velocity on the y axis when the ball hits the bottom of the canvas, stops changing the algebraic sign, after the first successful jump/bounce and the ball glitches at the bottom.

I have tried printing out some stuff if it gets into the function *moveBubbleUp()* and it printed when it was glitching at the bottom of the screen and was supposed to move up again, so why wont the algebraic sign change? When printing the velocity, it gets bigger and bigger, even though the *moveBubbleUp()* has *bubbleVelocity-=5* in it.

So the method gets called, proven by printing a random string when it enters it, but doesn't do anything i want it to, while also doing exactly what its counterpart *moveBubbleDown()* is supposed to do.
Which doesn't get called when the glitch happens, since i have tried printing something there as well.

Here are the methods that change the velocity:

```
void moveBubbleDown() {
    bubbleSpeedY += 5;
    bubbleVelocityY = bubbleSpeedY;
}

void moveBubbleUp() {
    bubbleSpeedY -= 5;
    bubbleVelocityY = -bubbleSpeedY;
}
```

and here are the methods, that call the functions and then change the y-Pos depending on them :

```
    //calculates YPos of bubble


    //changes which method should be called, if the ball has left the border 
    //and sets him on the edge of it
        if (bubble.getTranslateY()>=heightPane-radiusBubble) {
            bubble.setTranslateY(heightPane-radiusBubble);
            moveDown=false;
        } else if (bubble.getTranslateY() <= maxHeight) {
            bubble.setTranslateY(maxHeight);
            moveDown=true;
        }

        if (moveDown) {
            moveBubbleDown();
        } else {
            moveBubbleUp();
        }
        final double deltaYBubble = elapsedSeconds * bubbleVelocityY;
        bubble.setTranslateY(bubble.getTranslateY() + deltaYBubble);
```

To not leave anything out i'll post the rest of the code, so that you can try it yourself aswell:

```
   import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
   import javafx.application.Application;
   import javafx.scene.Parent;
   import javafx.scene.Scene;
   import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
   import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
   import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
   import javafx.stage.Stage;

   public class Main extends Application {

       //Global Variables
       private static final int widthPane = 1000;
       private static final int heightPane = 650;
       long lastUpdateTime = 0;

       //canvas
       private Pane root = new Pane();

       //Enemy
       int bubbleSpeedY = 30;
       int bubbleVelocityY = bubbleSpeedY;
       final int bubbleSpeedX = 200;
       int bubbleVelocityX = 0;
       int radiusBubble = 25;
       boolean moveDown=true;
       boolean moveRight=true;
       int maxHeight = 50;
       private Circle bubble = new Circle(radiusBubble, Color.CADETBLUE);

       private Parent createContent() {
           root.setPrefSize(widthPane, heightPane);

           root.getChildren().addAll(bubble);

           return root;
       }

       @Override
       public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

           bubble.setTranslateY(maxHeight);
           bubble.setTranslateX((int)(Math.random()*widthPane));

           Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());

           final AnimationTimer gameAnimation = new AnimationTimer() {
               @Override
               public void handle(long timestamp) {
                   update(timestamp);
               }
           };
           gameAnimation.start();

           stage.setScene(scene);
           stage.show();
       }


       /**
        * changes velocity so that the bubble goes to the right
        */
       void moveBubbleRight() {
           bubbleVelocityX = bubbleSpeedX;
       }

       /**
        * changes velocity so that the bubble goes to the left
        */
       void moveBubbleLeft() {
           bubbleVelocityX =-bubbleSpeedX;
       }

       void moveBubbleDown() {
           bubbleSpeedY += 5;
           bubbleVelocityY = bubbleSpeedY;
       }

       void moveBubbleUp() {
           bubbleSpeedY -= 5;
           bubbleVelocityY = -bubbleSpeedY;
       }


       /**
        * updates the pos of the bubble depending on the velocity,
        * looks if it's about to leave the border,
        * and sets it on the edge if it is
        *
        * @param timestamp helps calculate the time that has passed since the last update / frame
        */
       private void update(long timestamp) {
           if (lastUpdateTime > 0) {

        
               final double elapsedSeconds = (timestamp - lastUpdateTime) / 1_000_000_000.0 ;


               //bubble
               //calculates YPos of bubble


               //changes which method should be called, if the ball has left the border 
               //and sets him on the edge of it
               if (bubble.getTranslateY()>=heightPane-radiusBubble) {
                   bubble.setTranslateY(heightPane-radiusBubble);
                   moveDown=false;
               } else if (bubble.getTranslateY() <= maxHeight) {
                   bubble.setTranslateY(maxHeight);
                   moveDown=true;
               }

               if (moveDown) {
                   moveBubbleDown();
               } else {
                   moveBubbleUp();
               }
               final double deltaYBubble = elapsedSeconds * bubbleVelocityY;
               bubble.setTranslateY(bubble.getTranslateY() + deltaYBubble);


               //calculates XPos of Bubble
               if (bubble.getTranslateX() >= widthPane - radiusBubble) {
                   bubble.setTranslateX(widthPane - radiusBubble);
                   moveRight=false;
               } else if (bubble.getTranslateX() - radiusBubble <= 0) {
                   moveRight=true;
               }

               if (moveRight) {
                   moveBubbleRight();
               } else {
                   moveBubbleLeft();
               }

               final double deltaXBubble = elapsedSeconds * bubbleVelocityX;

               bubble.setTranslateX(bubble.getTranslateX() + deltaXBubble);

           }
           lastUpdateTime=timestamp;
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           launch(args);
       }
   }
```

Thanks for everyone trying to help, since I'm not so familiar with coding yet, and I think the problem is far beyond my knowledge of code. Well, or maybe its a stupidly small error that I have overlooked thats ruining everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the velocity at the time you hit the "floor". Simple timing changes can make it so it doesn't happen.  I think the velocity is such that the bubble doesn't properly get away from the floor so it is stuck triggering the condition of hitting the floor.   I added a print of vertical bubble velocity right after the moveUp/Down calls and then it stopped getting stuck!

I've made a minor change to your code to simplify the vertical movement and things seem to be better:

```
package stackoverflow.answers.demo;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    //Global Variables
    private static final int widthPane = 1000;
    private static final int heightPane = 650;
    long lastUpdateTime = 0;

    //canvas
    private Pane root = new Pane();

    //Enemy
    double bubbleAccelerationY = 300;
    double bubbleSpeedY = 30;
    double bubbleVelocityY = bubbleSpeedY;
    final int bubbleSpeedX = 200;
    int bubbleVelocityX = 0;
    int radiusBubble = 25;
    boolean moveDown = true;
    boolean moveRight = true;
    int maxHeight = 50;
    private Circle bubble = new Circle(radiusBubble, Color.CADETBLUE);

    private Parent createContent() {
        root.setPrefSize(widthPane, heightPane);
        root.getChildren().addAll(bubble);
        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        bubble.setTranslateY(maxHeight);
        bubble.setTranslateX((int) (Math.random() * widthPane));

        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());

        final AnimationTimer gameAnimation = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long timestamp) {
                update(timestamp);
            }
        };
        gameAnimation.start();

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * changes velocity so that the bubble goes to the right
     */
    void moveBubbleRight() {
        bubbleVelocityX = bubbleSpeedX;
    }

    /**
     * changes velocity so that the bubble goes to the left
     */
    void moveBubbleLeft() {
        bubbleVelocityX = -bubbleSpeedX;
    }

    void accelerateBubble(double secs) {
        bubbleVelocityY += (secs * bubbleAccelerationY);
    }

    void bounceBubble() {
        bubbleVelocityY = -bubbleVelocityY;
    }

    /**
     * updates the pos of the bubble depending on the velocity, looks if it's about to leave the border, and sets it on
     * the edge if it is
     *
     * @param timestamp helps calculate the time that has passed since the last update / frame
     */
    private void update(long timestamp) {
        if (lastUpdateTime > 0) {

            final double elapsedSeconds = (timestamp - lastUpdateTime) / 1_000_000_000.0;

            //bubble
            //calculates YPos of bubble
            //changes which method should be called, if the ball has left the border
            //and sets him on the edge of it
            if (bubble.getTranslateY() >= heightPane - radiusBubble) {
                bubble.setTranslateY(heightPane - radiusBubble);
                bounceBubble();
            } else if (bubble.getTranslateY() <= maxHeight) {
                bubble.setTranslateY(maxHeight);
            }

            accelerateBubble(elapsedSeconds);

            final double deltaYBubble = elapsedSeconds * bubbleVelocityY;
            bubble.setTranslateY(bubble.getTranslateY() + deltaYBubble);

            //calculates XPos of Bubble
            if (bubble.getTranslateX() >= widthPane - radiusBubble) {
                bubble.setTranslateX(widthPane - radiusBubble);
                moveRight = false;
            } else if (bubble.getTranslateX() - radiusBubble <= 0) {
                moveRight = true;
            }

            if (moveRight) {
                moveBubbleRight();
            } else {
                moveBubbleLeft();
            }

            final double deltaXBubble = elapsedSeconds * bubbleVelocityX;

            bubble.setTranslateX(bubble.getTranslateX() + deltaXBubble);

        }
        lastUpdateTime = timestamp;
    }
}
```